# Postgres, выбор поля по нескольким параметрам одного столбца

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица `user_chest` с примерным содержанием:

```
userId  |  status
--------|----------------
 1111   |   new
 1111   |   unlockprocess
 2222   |   new
 3333   |   unlockprocess
 4444   |   new
 4444   |   new
 5555   |   unlockprocess
 5555   |   new
```

Как выбрать только тех пользователей, у которых есть в "status" значение "new", но при этом нет значения "unlockprocess"?

Например из таблицы выше, должны выбраться только пользователи с `userId` 222 и 444.

Answer (score 5):

Например так (если условий только два):

```
select * from user_chest A
 where status='new'
   and not exists(select 1 from user_chest B
                   where B.userId=A.userId
                     and B.status='unlockprocess'
                 )
```

Или за один проход по таблице, зато с группировкой:

```
select user,max(status)
  from user_chest
 group by user
having max(case status when 'new' then 1 when 'unlockprocess' then 2 else 0 end)=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно через подзапрос, используя **`in`**:

```
select userid
from user_chest
where status = 'new'
      and userid not in (select userid
                         from user_chest
                         where status = 'unlockprocess')
```

---

Либо через соединение таблиц **`left join`**:

```
select userid
from user_chest a left join (select userid
                             from user_chest
                             where status = 'unlockprocess') b
     on a.userid = b.userid
where status = 'new'
      and b.userid is null
```

Результат в обоих случаях - разность двух множеств с `userid`.

Comment: Спасибо, а подскажите как добавить в выдачу "status" и сделать групировку по "userId"? У меня пишется: "ОШИБКА: столбец "user_chests.status" должен фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции Позиция: 32"

Comment: @Sergey Надо видимо решить какой статус вам нужен в случае группировки, например максимальный или минимальный. И если уж будет группировка то я бы предложил совершенно иной способ проверки статусов ...

Comment: @Sergey не совсем понятно, зачем вам группировка по `userid`. Если вы делаете группировку по `userid`, то у вас на `status` должны быть использованы агрегатные функции sum, count, min, max, avg.